# How to use systemColor in the opposite way

Tags: ios, swift

I want to use `systemColor` in the opposite way in iOS13 `UIColor`, for example, systemGray6 is (242,242,247) in LightMode and (28,28,30) in DarkMode, but I want to use (242,242,247) in DarkMode and (28,28,30) in LightMode. What should I do? [Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/color/):

> Don't hard-code system color values in your app. The color values
> provided below are intended for reference during your app design
> process. The actual color values may fluctuate from release to
> release, based on a variety of environmental variables. Always use the
> API to apply system colors; for developer guidance, see [`UIColor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/).

so how can I use `systemColor` in the opposite way and avoid hard-code system color values?

Answer (score 2):

Simple Answer is create new colour set

First go to your project **Assets** .Add new colour set.

Then change it's appearance  to Any,Dark,Light. set colours what you want in light or dark.

Now you use this colour in anywhere as color

```
something.color = UIColor(named:"myColor")
```

[image: Create new color set]
[image: change appearance]
[image: set colors]